# android Layout Spacing

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm new to Android dev so sorry for what is probably a basic question....

I'm trying to get 2 textviews to appear at the top of the screen and take up an equal amount of space each BUT to have a margin of say 20dp between the 2 views and on the left and the right hand side of the screen.

Much like

[image]

My code currently is:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#A1887F" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id ="@+id/1_Heading"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="#4CAF50"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  />

<TextView
    android:id ="@+id/2_Heading"
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="#4CAF50"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  />  

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas and sorry if this is a basic question - I've tried to find a solution online but nothing much helps.

Comment: So, what's the problem with your current layout?

Comment: did you tried to use 'match_parent' instead of '0dp' ? And for first text use alos layout_marginRight ="20d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give half right margin to your first Textview and half left margin to your second Textview as below:-

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A1887F"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id ="@+id/1_Heading"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  />

    <TextView
        android:id ="@+id/2_Heading"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: looks good - although I think on reflection my main issue was the emulator wasn't displaying things correctly! All sorted now though.

How would I start a second line of 2 text views?

Comment: create a new LinearLayout set its orientation to vertical paste the above LinearLayout in it twice and give all the TextViews unique id's

Comment: that doesn't appear to work :( I just get the first 2 and nothing else displayed underneath

Comment: sorted - needed to change the layout_height of my top linearlayout to wrap_content from match_parent

Comment: Set the parent Linearlayout height to 'wrapcontent'

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A1887F"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id ="@+id/1_Heading"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  />

    <TextView
        android:id ="@+id/2_Heading"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can handle this with giving a 20dp padding to parent (LinearLayout) and then 10dp margin from end to the first button, and 10dp margint from start to the second button.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#A1887F"
android:padding="20dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="#4CAF50"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="#4CAF50"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this layout xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A1887F"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A1887F"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id ="@+id/Heading_1"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  />

    <TextView
        android:id ="@+id/Heading_2"
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Results : [image]

Answer (score 0):

- Give `android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"`on the First TextView
- Give `android:layout_marginStart="10dp"`on the Second TextView

[Was Able to achieve this using below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKgx8.png)

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A1887F"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:text="2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```